# How to write java entity class supporting collection of nested tuples?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I need to store data in cassandra which needs one column to support list of nested tuples. Below is a small part of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
  k int PRIMARY KEY,
  v list<frozen<tuple<int, tuple<int, int>>>>
);
```

I tried to create the entity class but not sure how to use Tuple or TupleValue. I am okay with user defined types too if it solves the problem.

I was using the following dependency in the project so far.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But I came to know from other posters here that we need to use the following to use Tuples.

```
 <!--       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
```

But I still couldn't import any class or could write any entity class which will solve my problem.

**UPDATE**: Trying to use UDT rather than Tuples. Succeeded from the cqlsh console to insert the records as per my requirement. Working on the entity class. Fingers crossed.

```
CREATE TYPE cpi.ABC (
x int,
y int
);

CREATE TYPE cpi.XYZ (
num int,
aBC FROZEN <ABC>
);

CREATE TABLE user_table (
  k int PRIMARY KEY,
  v list<frozen<XYZ>>
);

INSERT INTO user_table (k, v) VALUES(10000, [{num:2,aBC:{x:3,y:4}}, {num:3,aBC:{x:4,y:5}}]);
```

Comment: What have you achieved so far? What is your current code? What is the error you get?

Comment: Updated the question description. Please have a look. Thanks !